# Деление до приближенного числа

Tags: java

Нужно найти *число итераций* деления числа `Х` на 2, до момента, пока `Х` будет максимально **приблежен** до числа `У`.

```
counterItteration = 0;
public int iteration(){

counterItteration++;
 if(x / 2 != (число максимально приблеженное к 512) { iteration(); }

return counterItteration;
}
```

Код написал прямо тут, так что скорее всего он нерабочий, но он покажет суть моего вопроса.

Comment: `скорее всего он нерабочий` - то есть, вы не попробовали? Пожалуйста попробуйте, и если не работает, объясните какой результат ожидаете.

Comment: @PeterOlson а смысл его пробовать, если в примере задана конкретная цифра 512, и он при делении будет искать ее, а мне нужна цифра, которая приближена максимально до 512. Можно вписать проверку на деление последующей итерации, если **меньше** чего то, то **вернуть** количество.

Comment: @PeterOlson к примеру у нас есть число равное 2264, делим его на 2 = 1132. Результат опять делим на 2 = 566 (все, иттератор надо остановить), так как 566 приближено к 512. Это объясняется тем, что если 566 еще раз разделить на 2 то будет 283 (а это уж точно никак не приближено)

Comment: Ну дак впишите проверку свою, когда не получится - будете спрашивать. Здесь не выполняют работу за тех, кому самому лень

Comment: @pavlofff вы бы лучше по существу бы писали и если уж взялись помогать, то вопрос читать стоит внимательней. я написал, то, что пришло в голову, что бы объяснить свой вопрос. а не для того, что мне влом делать. Если бы я знал, как сделать такую проверку **(число максимально приблеженное к 512)**, я бы даже не спрашивал бы.

Comment: делите на два пока результат деления не станет меньше нужного числа, потом вычтите по модулю последний результат и предпоследний из нужного числа - какой результат меньше, то и искомое. ну и счетчик делений заведите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Математическая логика этой задачи, всегда требует проверки на приближенность сравнением двух итераций. Причем к 512 мы можем подойти как с положительной стороны, так и с отрицательной, поэтому надо проверять на каждом шаге текущую и последующую итерацию. Варианты с одной стороны проверяются намного проще. Вычисления проводятся до того, пока следующая итерация не будет отрицательной.

```
if (a < 512 && b > 512 ) {
requiredNumber = ( abs(512 - a) < abs (b - 512) ) ? a : b;
}
```

Когда это будет выполнено, можно будет сказать число итераций и нужное число.

Comment: Работает, спасибо Вам большое !